# Virtual Machine on Windows 8.1 without Hyper-V

Tags: windows-8.1, virtual-machine

Is there a way I can install the latest version of Ubuntu on my Windows 8.1 machine without Hyper-V? I do not have Windows 8.1 Pro in order to have Hyper-V.

All guides I see on the subject do it via Hyper-V !! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the free version of VMware, or VirtualBox.